# Different color

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, color, gnuplot

I use the following code to generate a plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colorize your documents
\usepackage{graphicx}       % and use graphics
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}  % cool tikz-package for drawing
% improve the default settings for coordinate system drawing
\pgfplotsset{%
default/.style={grid=major,
        axis lines=middle,
        inner axis line style={=>},
        legend style={at={( 1.1,1)}, anchor=north west}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[default,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$\vert x\vert$
    ]
    % invoke external gnuplot as
    \addplot[thick,cyan,domain=-5.5:5.5] gnuplot[id=abs]{abs(x)};
    \addlegendentry{$\vert x\vert$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I use **pdflatex** on Ubuntu 13.10 and Debian Squeeze. I get different results:

debian:

[image: plot on debian]

ubuntu:

[image: plot on ubuntu]

Maybe there are different color definitions in different package version. Whats the best way to investigate where the reason is.

edit: "\listfiles" gives me (on debian):

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
```

and on ubuntu

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
```

Comment: The first picture uses `cyan` color....

Comment: The best way to investigate begins by giving a MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Presumably related to the viewer. The second picture shows me what is defined as "cyan" in »[xcolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)« (Section 2.4). And this is also what I get when compiling the code.

Comment: So I have to consult the xcolor package on both systems? I use only the color package. This was a MWE. The preamble only contains the required minimal packages "usepackage{ tikz,color,pgfplots,graphicx}". How can I made my code "portable"?

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article about Cyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyan) I have learned that there is a "Print Cyan" and a "Web Cyan", which seem to match here respectively. But that doesn't answer why you get those different colors in the output.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I add a compileable MWE.

Comment: Even `\usepackage[CMYK]{xcolor}` does not change the first picture into the second on my debian machine.

Comment: I get the first picture when I insert `\usepackage[RGB]{xcolor}` before loading »[pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)«. Since »[xcolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)« is already loaded by »[pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)« (or »tikz« respectively), this is done without that option, which means that colors are depicted in the CMYK model. But that still doesn't answer why two different systems use different color models.

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to your document and compare the log files.

Comment: I suspect that you have different versions of packages installed across the two systems.  Perhaps pgf/tikz loads xcolor with different default options or deals differently with a preloaded color package.

Comment: I know that you tried many things already but can you also add `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` before everything including the document class declaration?

Comment: I would expect that the entire issue is unrelated to both `tikz` and `pgfplots`. In other words: the same should appear with something like `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{cyan}{THIS IS CYAN TEXT}
\end{document}`

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: exactly |
@percusse: it does not change anything |

I add the result of the `\listfiles` command

Comment: Out of curiosity, what document viewer do you use? I assume `evince` on ubuntu but what about debian? Have u tried to use similar viewer (e.g. adobe acrobat) on both?

Comment: This is then a viewer issue.

Comment: I opened both pdf with the default pdf viewer of ubuntu

Comment: The versions of `pdftex.def` differ between your systems!  Does the first line of your `.log` files differ between your systems?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible with the provided information.